# Insulating the controller from the view in C when there are collections involved

Tags: c, model-view-controller, macros

I'm experimenting with using pre-processor macros to implement something like a templating engine in C, with the goal of allowing something like a typical MVC pattern. The application will probably be a simple static site generator with just the basic level of functionality that I can live with. The goal is mostly a learning experience, but I would also find it useful to have an SSG that both meets my needs and that I can completely understand.

I'm pretty pleased with how clean it seems to be turning out (clean being a relative term here, since I normally find macros to be anything but clean), but I'm not totally happy with how I'm handling collections. This amounts to what other frameworks call a repeater. The part that bothers me is that the controller has to know that the parent view consists of 3 sections: before the repeater, the repeater, and after the repeater. This could also apply to any views that need to reference multiple models (headers, navbars, etc.). Is there an established way of encapsulating this in C? Can it be done? *Should* it be done?

Here's the gist of what I've done:

---

```
/*tag.h*/
#ifndef TAG_H
#define TAG_H

#define tag(name,children) "<" name ">" children "</" name ">"
#define stag(name,attrs) "<" name " " attrs ">"
#define etag(name) "</" name ">"

#endif
```

---

```
/*child_model.h*/
#ifndef CHILD_MODEL_H
#define CHILD_MODEL_H

struct child
{
    char *detail;
};

#endif
```

---

```
/*child_view.h*/
#ifndef CHILD_VIEW_H
#define CHILD_VIEW_H

#include "tag.h"
#include "child_model.h"

#define child_view(m) \
    tag("li", "%s"),\
    (m).detail\

#endif
```

---

```
/*parent_model.h*/
#ifndef PARENT_MODEL_H
#define PARENT_MODEL_H

struct parent
{
    char *title;
    char *subtitle;
};

#endif
```

---

```
/*parent_view.h*/
#ifndef PARENT_VIEW_H
#define PARENT_VIEW_H

#include "tag.h"
#include "parent_model.h"

#define parent_view_s1(m) \
    stag("html","")\
        tag("head",\
            tag("title", "%s")\
        )\
        stag("body","")\
            tag("h1", "%s")\
            tag("p", "%s")\
            stag("ul",""),\
    (m).title,\
    (m).title,\
    (m).subtitle\

#define parent_view_s2(m) \
            etag("ul")\
        etag("body")\
    etag("html")\

#endif
```

---

```
/*controller.c*/
#include "parent_model.h"
#include "parent_view.h"
#include "child_model.h"
#include "child_view.h"

int
example_controller(int (*render)(void *, const char *, ...), void *render_ctx, struct parent *p, struct child *chlist, int n)
{
    int i;
    int e;
    /*render, here, is effectively like fprintf: render_ctx holds the stream information, and the view macro expands to the format string and args*/
    e = render(render_ctx, parent_view_s1(*p));
    if(e < 0) return e;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        e = render(render_ctx, child_view(chlist[i]));
        if(e < 0) return e;
    }
    e = render(render_ctx, parent_view_s2(*p));
    if(e < 0) return e;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would probably be a better question for codereview.stackexchange.

Comment: It seemed more widely applicable in my head before I wrote it. Reading it now, I see what you mean and agree. I'm having trouble finding anything on meta about migration other than policy discussion. What's the actual process?

Comment: Flag the question, select "other", and ask for the question to be migrated.